# Using a Material-based Dialog Theme with AppCompat

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat, material-design

I have an activity in my Manifest I used to style with a Dialog Theme.  I can not find how to replace this in `AppCompat` library.

```
  <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:styles/Theme.Holo.Dialog" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Login" >
```

Is there a Material-based equivalent?

Comment: see my answer to your other question which will probably work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595128/appcompat-dialog-theme-with-mis-colored-titlebar-bug/27069935

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no material based theme for a dialog in AppCompat yet, see [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#comment-1641346011)

`Will appcompat automatically theme dialogs to look like the Lollipop version?`

Response

`Not yet, but it's on the todo list.`

**Update:**

In version `22.1` of the `Support Library` you can now get the material dialog style by using [AppCompatDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDialog)

Comment: Wonder if it will happen before the official Nov 3 release

Comment: Since Google didn't publish such a thing yet, I've made a library for this: github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialStuffLibrary

Comment: @KickingLettuce out of curiosity, where can one see future release dates of AppCompat, and maybe notes about what changed? I can't find anything similar.

Comment: @miav That was just a rumor i found online and i don't think It was 100% accurate as it turned out

Comment: FYI: This was released with appcompat v22.1.0

Answer (score 58):

**Java code**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle("SCRUM");
            builder.setMessage("In the SCRUM methodology a sprint is the basic unit of development. Each sprint is preceded by a planning meeting, where the tasks for the sprint are identified and an estimated commitment for the sprint goal is made, and followed by a review or retrospective meeting where the progress is reviewed and lessons for the next sprint are identified. During each sprint, the team creates finished portions of a product.....");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);//second parameter used for onclicklistener
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.show();
```

**Use this theme**

```
  <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#5fa3d0</item>
</style>
```

**Import support v7 alert dialog**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

**Output like this,**

[image]

Comment: Nice!! I am using a list in alert Dialog, seems no way to change the text color for list item? I tried text color secondary and list Item, but has no effect!

Comment: what if the dialog extends DialogFragment, how to handle the error "NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.setFocusable(boolean)' on a null object reference"?

Comment: Oh mannnn ! You are amazingggggggggggg .. Where have you been for last 3 hours I have tried to find you :D .

Comment: I' using ANDROIDX and this was not working for me. The button was getting a white background. The only solution I found when using AndroidX was the answer from @Rob on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829954/materialcomponents-theme-alert-dialog-buttons

Answer (score 9):

Use the latest Appcompat library

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'// or any version greater than 22.1
```

and in Manifest use the following theme

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

I used it to build the dialog in a `DialogFragment`, with custom styles applied. Works great.

Comment: were you able to change the background of the title on the dialogs?

Comment: There isn't a background for the title, it's the background of the whole thing: https://github.com/hyperboria/android/pull/21 (bottom picture)