# Why is the radiobutton text white in this android alertdialog and how to I change it?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I am trying to do a very basic alertdialog to show some options to select -  am trying it as shown but the text for the options is white on a white background.  Is there a simple way to change it without making a bunch of xml files?  Maybe make a single style?

```
 CharSequence[] array = {"Red", "Blue", "Yellow"};
        new AlertDialog.Builder( new ContextThemeWrapper( getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert))
                .setSingleChoiceItems(array, 0, null)
                .setTitle(R.string.selectweightclass)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                        Log.d(TAG, "selectedPosition= "+selectedPosition);

                        // Do something useful withe the position of the selected radio button
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

[image]

PS:  Turns out R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert is good enough for now.  Those *DayNight* themes were messing me up.

Comment: The problem is the theme you choosed for your AlertDialog

Comment: I was thinking that maybe one of my styles was conflicting with it but I changed them around and the text stayed white.    What style should I choose?  Is there a guide to selecting these styles?  It is pretty much hit and miss for me.

Comment: If you are already using a Theme like this `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` for your application, you could simply remove the style from the AlertDialog and create the builder in this way `new AlertDialog.Builder(context)`. If you need a custom style for the AlertDialog, you should create a new style inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` or something similar and then apply it to the Dialog as you already did. [Read here for an help on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30975075/2910520)

Comment: Thanks,
 Turns out R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert is good enough for now.