# MaterialComponents theme alert dialog buttons

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-styles, material-components-android

Recently I switched from support library to com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0

But now I have a problem, in this pages there's a note https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

> Note: Using a Material Components theme enables a custom view inflater which replaces default components with their Material counterparts. Currently, this only replaces Button XML components with MaterialButton.

And the theme I am using

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
```

does exactly what it says in that note, it replaces AlertDialog Buttons to MaterialButtons but the problem is that by default MaterialButtons are colored background and now the buttons looks like this: [image]

How can I make them borderless and backgroundless again?

PS I am using alert builder to create alert dialogs:

```
android.app.AlertDialog.Builder
```

Comment: You can use Bridge theme if you want AppCompat theme contents with some new Material UI styles, it can solve your problem, refer my this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52401497/10271334

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this problem. I need to use different AlertDialog class:

```
androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
```

When I switched to this everything started working as expected. Here's where I found the solution:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/162

Comment: I migrated my code to androidx using the Android Studio's 'Migrate to AndroidX' option/feature but this library was not updated to AndroidX automatically. This issue for me was resolved when I updated the import manually as the answer suggests

Answer (score 93):

When using `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` and `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` you can customize each button in the `buttonBar` by using `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton` as parent.

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertDialogTheme))
```

Use the default layout or add a custom by `builder.setView(R.layout.my_dialog)`

In your styles:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Positive</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Neutral</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Neutral</item>
</style>

<style name="Alert.Button.Positive" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="Alert.Button.Neutral" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is what I was looking for when trying to style my dialogs. All answers I found were not using AndroidX.

Comment: I'm just not sure why you're setting up textAllCaps to false. I usually see it set to true on dialogs (the only exception was a Material Design example from google called Crane)

Comment: @LeonardoSibela Yea, default behaviour sets all buttons to textAllCaps=true, updated

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 50 times. I spent like two hours trying to just color stupid dialogs. Note that you should also use `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` instead.

Comment: @gMale 's comment saved time for me.

Answer (score 30):

If you are using the Material Components library the best way to have an `AlertDialog` is to use the [`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md).

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Dialog")
            .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null)
            .show();
```

It is the default result:

[image]

If you want also to apply a different style or color to the buttons you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053520/change-dialog-button-color/58043299#58043299).

Comment: Replacing `AlertDialog.Builder` with `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` didn't change a color of buttons. See answers below to change the `theme`.

Comment: @CoolMind The question is not how to change the button color.

Comment: Use `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(fa, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)` to change button styling...

Answer (score 21):

First, it's better to use use [MaterialAlertDialog](https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialog/) if you are using Material Theme.

You can read more here – [Material.io → Theming dialogs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialogs/#theming-dialogs)

[image]

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle(R.string.confirm)
            .setMessage(R.string.logout)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.logout_alert_positive) { _, _ -> activity?.logout() }
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.never_mind, null)
            .show()
```

[This](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/e22d745ec096154ee0028c2dd180ea4ae6248eda/lib/java/com/google/android/material/dialog/res/layout/mtrl_alert_dialog_actions.xml) is the layout.xml of the MaterialAlertDialog actions. As you can see there are 3 buttons and each has their own styles. So, here is how you can change them.

**Step 1:** Tell Android that you want to alter the default [MaterialAlertDialog](https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialog/) theme.

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**Step 2:** Tell Android that you want to alter a specific button style. `buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle`, `buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle` or `buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle`

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

**Step 3:** Define your custom style

```
<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 20):

I tested the above answers. Although I got a good idea, none worked for my case. So, this is my answer.

1. Make sure to have `android:theme="@style/AppMaterialTheme"` in your manifest file under Application or Activity.
2. Open your Styles.xml file and change it based on the following.

   ```
   <style name="AppMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryBlue</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryBlue</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primaryBlue</item>
       <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent_main</item>
       <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>

       <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogMaterialTheme</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AlertDialogMaterialTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
       <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Positive</item>
       <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Negative</item>
   </style>

   <style name="Alert.Button.Positive" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
       <item name="android:fillColor">@color/color_0054BB</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
       <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
       <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
       <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent_main</item>
   </style>

   <style name="Alert.Button.Negative" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
       <item name="strokeColor">@color/color_0054BB</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_0054BB</item>
       <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
       <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">8dp</item>
       <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent_main</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. You won't need to apply the theme to your AlertDialog as your Activity applies the theme to it. So, create the dialog normally.

[image]

The result will be.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, by "buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle" is not working for me but "android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle" is working properly.

Comment: The style is not applying to PositiveButton. The same with Negative one.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`, you can just redefine the style of the dialog buttons:

In your style.xml :

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
   ...
   <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogButton</item>
   ...
</style>

<style name="DialogButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Found another solution for this with using MaterialComponents here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116861837#comment9

```
<style name="Theme.Custom.Material.Alert.Dialog.Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Custom.Material.Base.Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Theme.Custom.Material.Alert.Dialog.Light</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Custom.Material.Alert.Dialog.Light</item>
  ....
</style>
```

Though it is still not "intended behavior" to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` library, using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` works as expected.