# How can I change positive/negative button background color in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

[image: Cancel and add backfround button]

I'm using `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`, because I want rounded corner and both day and night mode. And please note that I cannot use `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));` line because in my style I've different parent in style.xml which I uses to set color according to day/night mode.

Question: How can I change positive/negative button background color in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder?

Please note that drawable background is not working in `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`

Code:

```
public void showNotesDialog() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder alertDialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.dialogBoxStyle);
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_note_layout, null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        etNote = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.et_note);
        String buttonName = getString(R.string.add);
        if (!getNotes.isEmpty()) {
            buttonName = getString(R.string.update);
            etNote.getText().clear();
            etNote.setText(getNotes);
        }

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(buttonName, null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Clear", null);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);


        alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button buttonPositive = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                Button buttonNegative = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                Button buttonClear = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
                buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        etNote.getText().clear();
                        getNotes = "";
                        noteDesc.setText(getNotes);
                    }
                });

                buttonPositive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        getNotes = etNote.getText().toString();
                        noteDesc.setText(getNotes);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                buttonNegative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

**Styles (v21)**

```
 <style name="dialogBoxStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">?attr/day_colorWhite_night_colorVeryDarkBlackMostlyBlack</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <!--TODO: Please note that "cornerSize" will give effect on outside of Dialog Box border line, not where the row is inflated.-->
        <!--TODO: If you want to set Inside corner: app:cardCornerRadius="60dp"-->
        <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053520/change-dialog-button-color/58043299#58043299)

Comment: Also don't use `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert` as parent but `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog`. And since the MaterialAlertDialog is using MaterialButtons you can change the style of the button, using for example an OutlinedBox style as you can find in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043838/2016562)

Comment: @amin I don't have any code regarding dialogboxstyle in styles.xml. And for styles.xml(V21) I already posted in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code in your dialog

```
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
```

to change background then please refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043299/7579041)

Comment: I'm asking for backgroung also

Comment: for that, you need to make changes in your styles.xml file

Comment: yes tell me, what type of changes? can you please suggest me? Make sure you don't change parent because it should be according to day/night mode.

Comment: check the updated link