# Using MaterialAlertDialogBuilder with a material theme

Tags: android

I have set the android application to use the material theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

In my activity/fragment, I am trying to invoke the material alert dialog

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(mAppContext)
                            .setTitle("Title")
                            .setMessage("Message")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                            .show();
```

At runtime this is throwing the following IllegalArgumentException exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:240)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:211)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:146)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:78)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialDialogs.getDialogBackgroundInsets(MaterialDialogs.java:55)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.<init>(MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.java:116)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.<init>(MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.java:102)
        at com.syl.app.fragments.AlarmNotificationDetailFragment$2.onClick(UserFragment.java:265)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:941)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Isn't this contradictory? A material component requires AppCompat theme whereas the application uses a material theme.

The android documentation also says the same

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder requires that your application use a Material Components theme (e.g., Theme.MaterialComponents.Light). Using a Material Components theme with MaterialAlertDialogBuilder will result in an AlertDialog that matches your appplication’s color, typography, and shape theming.
```

How do I get the alert dialog to work in this case where I am using a material theme?

Comment: How do you get your `mAppContext` variable?

Comment: In case, anyone has a problem, I put my complete answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59110804/513413

Answer (score 4):

**Just do it with**

```
 Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(SelectImageActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme2);
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context);
```

**Your Theme if you are using MaterialComponents**

```
  <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yellow</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: What is the "SelectImageActivity", where is that from  ?
Is it the current activity where that code resides ?

Answer (score 2):

below is working for me

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@android:style/DeviceDefault.ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Material.SearchView</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Make usre you do not have multiple style.xml file for diff apis.