# Custom Dialog Alert

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make a custom dialog alert as shown in the picture; I tried and looked everywhere to make it look like the photo but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated; First picture shows what I want to make and the second what it looks like currently:

[image]

[image]

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)

        alert.setTitle("Confirm delete")
        alert.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.")

        alert.setPositiveButton("DELETE"){dialog, which ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Ok, we change the app background.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL"){dialog,which ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You are not agree.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        val dialog: AlertDialog = alert.create()

        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also share what result you're getting with code that you've provided

Comment: Can you try to show dialog onClick of any view ?

Comment: @KaranMehta  please see updates

Comment: @Niceumang Please see updates

Comment: The result that you want to achieve is older themed custom alert but your project theme might be material theme, that's why styling of the dialog is different, otherwise dialog is same

Comment: This is very old style of **Alert Dialog** which is deprecated. You can create your own view like this and set as view to Alert Dialog

Comment: You can get that same alert dialog with libraries available online\

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just use the [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896538/2016562)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert.Dialog theme depends on your device API levels.  In the first picture look like **Android KitKat (API 19 - 20)** ,in the second picture follows **material design pattern (API >20)**.

**If want to dialog like the first picture you may need make custom layout**

happy_coding

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**1.Create Kotlin class for Dialog**

```
class CustomDialog(
    context: Context,val mCallBack: CallBack
) : Dialog(context, R.style.full_screen_dialog) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)
        // YOUR COMPONENT HANDLE HERE
    // FOR EXAMPLE
        btn_yes.setOnClickListener {
              mCallBack.onDone()
              dismiss()
        }
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }
    }


    interface CallBack {
        //YOU CAN HANDLE THIS METHOD IN YOUR CALLING ACTIVITY
        fun onDone(rating: Float, comments: String)
    }

}
```

**2.How to call**

```
 var mDialog: CustomDialog = CustomDialog(
            this,
            object : CustomDialog.CallBack {
                override fun onDone() {

                }
            })
        mDialog.show()
```

**3.styles.xml**

```
<style name="full_screen_dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Create your own custom layout file and set it on `setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)` as I didn't mentioned here

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your dialog is displaying using material theme.
You can use below code to get required result by applying style to AlertDialog.

```
val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
```

Note: this style is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the help!