# How to change MaterialAlertDialog theme

Tags: java, android, android-theme

Here is a dialog, how to change this color (unchecked)?

[image: screenshot]

I try to set style but not work:

```
 <style name="ThemeMyAppDialogAlertDay"  
   parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/color_primary_variant</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_error</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please check with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829954/materialcomponents-theme-alert-dialog-buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
 <style name="ThemeMyAppDialogAlertDay"  
   parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
     <item name="colorSecondary">@color/selected</item> <!-- selected -->
     <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/unselected</item> <!-- unselected -->
 </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this , It should help

```
<style name="materialDiaog" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="buttonTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/color_primary_variant</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_error</item>


</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="{set your parent theme here}">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/materialDiaog</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried it, only the white circle cannot be changed

Comment: so what you want is to change the color for the uncheck  ?

Comment: the last time I had such a problem , adding `buttonTint` with the preferred color to the style was what help